# Get max value rows then min value rows, or if a subset has all Nan, keep everything

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```py
x = pd.DataFrame({
    "t": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"],
    "m": ["k", "m", "m", "k", "m", "m", "b", "k", "f", "d"],
    "f1": [1.2, np.nan,  0.8, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    "f2": [100, 200, 200, 100, 100, 100, 50, 200, 300, 400]})
```

```
   t  m   f1   f2
0  A  k  1.2  100
1  A  m  NaN  200
2  A  m  0.8  200
3  B  k  1.0  100
4  B  m  1.0  100
5  B  m  1.5  100
6  B  b  1.0   50
7  A  k  NaN  200
8  C  f  NaN  300
9  C  d  NaN  400
```

On `f1` I want to pick min value of each subgroup `t`. If a subgroup has Nan values, we need to pick all the values. On `f2` I want to pick max values. In case of Nan values, we need to keep all the rows. So I want an output something similar to

```
   t  m   f1   f2
0  A  m  0.8  200
1  B  k  1.0  100
2  B  m  1.0  100
3  C  d  NaN  400
```

I was able to achieve this using

```py
def keep_rows(k, col, op):
    # if all values are Nan 
    if np.isnan(k[col].values).all():
        return k 
    return k[k[col] == getattr(np, f"nan{op}")(k[col])]
```

```py
tt = x.groupby("t", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: keep_rows(x, "f1", "min")).reset_index(drop=True)
tt = tt.groupby("t", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: keep_rows(x, "f2", "max")).reset_index(drop=True)
tt
```

But is there a better way? Especially in pandas v2?

Comment: this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Then please explain the logic and how this is not a duplicate

Comment: firstly this is on multiple columns and need different operations on both of them and there can be multiple eligible rows. need a subset of it. I found the other question to be verbose and most of the answers are wrong. Also want to see if pandas v2 has any elegant solution for this.

Comment: This is not very clear in your question, nevertheless see the answer below if you need simultaneous conditions. If you want **successive** conditions, then this falls back to the duplicate.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Prakash tbf it was a duplicate originally, but now it's totally different yeah

Answer (score 1):

If the operations are simultaneous, you need a double [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

#### updated question

```
g = x.assign(flag=x['f1'].isna()).groupby('t')

# does the row have the min f1 or its group?
m1 = g['f1'].transform('min').eq(x['f1'])
# does the group have all NaN in f1?
m2 = g['flag'].transform('all')
# does the row have the max f2 or its group?
m3 = g['f2'].transform('max').eq(x['f2'])

out = x.loc[(m1 | m2) & m3]
```

Output:

```
   t  m   f1   f2
2  A  m  0.8  200
3  B  k  1.0  100
4  B  m  1.0  100
9  C  d  NaN  400
```

#### original question

```
g = x.groupby('t')

m1 = g['f1'].transform('min').eq(x['f1'])
m2 = g['f2'].transform('max').eq(x['f2'])

out = x.loc[m1 & m2]
```

If the operations are consecutive, then you fall back to a known problem, just chain two selections.

Output:

```
   t  m   f1   f2
1  A  m  0.8  200
2  B  k  1.0  100
3  B  m  1.0  100
```

Comment: thanks, what if `f1` contains np.nan and we want to include those rows. when using `transform(min)`, those rows are removed.

Comment: Then add a third condition: `m3 = x['f1'].isna()` and `out = x.loc[(m1&m2)|m3]`. Depending on your exact logic.

Comment: I have further edited this question. Please check once. Thanks